# Can I rewrite this String -> java.sql.Date question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Somebody recently asked [how to convert a String to a java.sql.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550796/conveting-string-date-to-java-sql-date). Of course, there are a zillion examples of this all over the place. There are also a number of questions on SO about it. Being sure this was a duplicate, I started looking around SO for a suitable source.

The best I could find, as far as the answer, was [convert string date to java.sql.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668329/convert-string-date-to-java-sql-date). However, even though the answer was all right, the question is terrible. I'd like to rewrite this question.

At this point, since the question is already closed, would it be acceptable for me to just rewrite it and vote to reopen (perhaps also requesting community wiki conversion)? It's still not the greatest answer, but it seems like the best one on SO for this particular question (it's the highest voted relevant answer).

Comment: Rewrite which one? The one from Mar 27 '13?

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Yes, that one. Edited to attempt clarification.

Comment: Actually, to be honest, looking at it, the more recent one has a decent collection of answers now. Perhaps I should find the other ones and mark them as duplicates of this new one?

Comment: If you think we have something approaching a good canon question for an issue that comes up a lot, sure.

Comment: I've got a better idea; I asked BalusC to update his answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion?lq=1 -- the question is worded ambiguously enough that `java.sql.Date` can be ninja'd in to the answer. Then that question can serve as the canonical source for both.

Comment: As BalusC reasonably declined to include that in his answer, I will rework one of the above questions, or simply post a self-answered question if that can't be done.